# Trying to plot all of the timestamps from a folder onto graph

Tags: matlab

I have a folder with 20,000+ data entries, and am trying to graph the time in-between each entry, to see where our process slows down.  I've been trying to use the Dir() function on Matlab, by combining a couple of different codes I've found, but I feel like I'm way out of my depth, and not even able to get the basic structure right.

```
for i=1:25910
  
   n = num2str(i);
   d = dir('P' n '_Bump.datx');
   moddate = d.date;
   Plot(n,moddate)
    
end
```

I'm more familiar with python if there's a similar function that could pull the timestamp off of a file in that.

Data is formatted like:

P1_Bump.datx

P2_Bump.datx

...

P25910_Bump.datx

Comment: Just do `files = dir('*_Bump.datx')` and loop over that. Then, create an output array where to store all your variables, rather than overwriting your plot every loop iteration (you've misspelled `plot` btb, it's not capitalised). It sounds like you'd benefit more from [going through MATLAB's starting tutorial](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html), rather than copying someone else's code from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull all of your files into a table (which is slightly easier to deal with than a struct in this case) like this:

```
files = dir( '*_Bump.datx' );
files = struct2table( files, 'AsArray', true );
```

Then get the dates from the `datenum` field of the table (since the `date` field is a char and not a MATLAB date)

```
dates = datetime( files.datenum, 'convertfrom', 'datenum' )
```

To calculate the time between files you can use `diff`

```
timesBetween = diff(dates);
```

Then plot

```
figure;
plot( timesBetween );
```

Note that `timesBetween` will be one element shorter than the number of files, since it's the differences in between files.